# Security On Folder Using PHp

Tags: php, url

My *Main Path* of My Application is as follow

```
http://example.com/login.php
```

If *User Login* and type is **seller** than

```
http://example.com/login.php/seller/index.php
```

If *User Login* and type is **caller** than

```
http://example.com/login.php/caller/index.php
```

**Problem :**

If seller is logged in and if he/she changes url

`http://example.com/login.php/seller/index.php`

to

`http://example.com/login.php/caller/index.php`

So php allows to change Whole Module. **So how can i prevent Seller to Enter in Caller Module.**
my application is in core php. no frameworks i used. and i have field in database named with type which have type like caller or seller or admin
and my database structure is as followw
[image]
Sorry i have hided Contact Credential. i hope it doesn't matter

Comment: On each module set a controller to check user type,After session start if it is a seller and tries caller redirect that user to seller again.

Comment: what do you mean by controller. my aplication is in core php. no framworks i used.

Comment: A controller can be anything to check the status, Even a simple if statement is a controller. Like this, if userType="seller" then redirect sellerpage. You need to type actual codes to redirect, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication)

Comment: Duplicate Question is not give me right answer. please remove Duplicate

Comment: If `psw` is their password, please look into encrypting users passwords with salts. http://plaintextoffenders.com/about/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by simply validating that a user has the correct account type, or access rights as it were to view each module. As there is no code in your question, this answer is going to be generic, but should guide you to be able to implement a similar solution in your own application.

So, you have two routes:

**Seller**

`http://example.com/login.php/seller/index.php`

**Caller**

`http://example.com/login.php/caller/index.php`

As Daniel wrote in the above answer, you could store the account types in a session variable. As there is a field in the database which stores the account type of each user, you can fetch this and store it.

When the user logs in, you can fetch this information from the database, and store it in a session:

```
<?php

// Login page

//...code to login user

$accountType = $queryResultAccountType; // Fetch the user's role from the database,

$_SESSION['account_type'] = $accountType; // Store it in the session
```

Now, for each of your module pages, simply check to see if the user accessing the module has the correct account type:

**Seller Route: index.php**

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['account_type']) || $_SESSION['account_type'] != 'seller') {
    exit('No permission');
}

// load page here if they do have permission
```

**Caller Route: index.php**

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['account_type']) || $_SESSION['account_type'] != 'caller') {
    exit('No permission');
}

// load page here if they do have permission
```

This is a very broad and basic example, but hopefully you get the idea. You can adapt this to redirect them, show custom views and so on. I would highly recommend using a framework in future though, as a lot of this bare-bone functionality is already handled for you, in a much more robust way.

Answer (score 1):

Store logged user 'role' in session upon login process

Example :

```
$_SESSION['role'] = 'caller'
```

In each module check user 'role'

If your clinet/index.php and seller/index.php is sharing same code, you can get exact URI from

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

```
if (!preg_match('!(caller|seller)/index.php!',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$m))
{
        die("Wrong access");
}

$role = $m[1];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: HOW CAN I CHECK ?? REQUEST_URI RETURNS ME FULL URL AND EVERY PAGE HAVE DIFFRENT NAME. BAD ANSWER :-(

Comment: Usually url checked with regular expression. Good to know if you gonna be programmer

Added  quick example to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add field `type` (`seller` or `caller`) in database of User
Every login, you check `type` with `seller` or `caller`